# Python how to realize sort with a customized encoding?

Tags: python, sorting

Say there is a simple list and `sorted` then get following result:

```
s=['university','university','college','school']
sorted(s)
Out[6]: ['college', 'school', 'university', 'university']
```

`sorted` will sort the list according to the inner encoding(utf-8 may be). I want to set a customized encoding. In the aboving example, I want to set a encoding as :`['university','college','school']`.I want sort  according to my customized encoding thus the result should be `sorted(s):['university','university','college','school']`.

How can I realize it in Python?

Comment: do you mean a customized *collation*?  Unicode strings aren't encoded.

Comment: @ Mark Tolonen  yeah I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, you can use the `key` parameter to pass a custom function that takes an element, performs a computation, and returns the value to sort.

In the case below, each element is looked up by index in the `order` list. For example, `'college'` returns `1` and `'university'` returns `0`, so `'university'` sorts before `'college'`.

```
order=['university','college','school']
s=['school','university','college','university']
print(sorted(s,key=lambda n: order.index(n)))
```

Output:

```
['university', 'university', 'college', 'school']
```